# Google bar chart with difference arrow

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Plain and simple, is it possible to do a bar chart like this one.. using google chart ?

[image]

I have no code to show you because is very simple to do bar chart but not sure if is possible to generate a difference arrow. (this graph is from Think Cell)

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I am aware of is [Diff Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/diffchart#diff-bar-and-column-charts).  They aren't nearly as explicit in marking the change, but they are a way to visually display the change in a data set.

Using DiffCharts requires to separate `google.visualization.DataTable` instances with the old data an new data.  You then call the `computeDiff(oldData, newData)` method on the chart instance and it will give you a new `DataTable` instance that you can use to draw the diff chart.